# how i can disable motion blur for specified objects in BGE?

Tags: game-engine

I need to enable motion blur filter for specified objects in the scene using python or something

Comment: how are you making the motion blur?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is you can't. The motion blur 3D filter in the BGE is accomplished by accumulating the previous frames together with the current frame, therefore it can't single out a specific object.

Answer (score 0):

According to a [thread by the user kitebizelt](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?401481) on Blender Artists, there actually seems to be a custom solution to achieve a PerObjectMotionBlur. As far as I understood, this is achieved by a custom vertex and fragment Shader attached to the to-be-blurred-object which use the velocity information (speed pass).

A Demo *blend is provided in the thread.